# Chaning JSoup Standard Charset

Tags: jsoup

Good evening,

I am currently using JSoup to handle my HTTP-Connection stuff and just encountered the problem that the server I am trying to interact with does not support other Charsets than ISO-8859-1.

From what I could gather on the internet and in the JSoup source, JSoup only supports UTF-8 for all requests.

```
static final String defaultCharset = "UTF-8"; // used if not found in header or meta charset
```

Would changing this String to the ISO-8859-1 change all request encoding or is there a catch I haven't found(understanding the JSoup source is really hard for me)?

Here is the code I am currently using to post data to the server:

```
Jsoup.connect(uploadsite).cookies(cookies)
            .header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")
            .data("Eintrag[]" , panel.teingangsdatum.getText(), "Ticket[]", panel.tticketnr.getText(),
            "DatumA[]", datumteile[2], "DatumB[]", datumteile[1], "DatumC[]", datumteile[0],
            "UhrzeitA[]", panel.tanfangsstunde.getText(), "UhrzeitB[]", panel.tanfangsminute.getText(),
            "UhrzeitC[]", panel.tendstunde.getText(), "UhrzeitD[]", panel.tendminute.getText(),
            "KundeA[]", kdname, "KundeB[]", panel.tkdnr.getText(), "HVT[]", 
            panel.thvt.getText(),
            "Techniker[]", "0", "Art[]", ticketart)
            .method(Method.POST)
            .execute();
```

Everything works fine besides the umlauts "öÖäÄüÜ".

Comment: Please include the code you're currently using.

Comment: @MattBall I don't understand your question. This is a question about the JSoup Source Code, which can be downloaded from their website(newest version).

Comment: How are _you_ trying to use JSoup to fetch data from this server?

Comment: @MattBall Ah right, added the requested code.

Comment: Why can't you change the `Content-Type` header from `charset=UTF-8` to `charset=ISO-8859-1`? The JSoup source code specifically says that the default charset is _"// used if not found in header or meta charset"_

Comment: @MattBall That didn't work. It still is the same output as with `charset=UTF-8` header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.postDataCharset("ISO-8859-1")`to your request ([javadoc](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/helper/HttpConnection.Request.html#postDataCharset-java.lang.String-)).

Example:

The string "ÄÖÜ-foobar" in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format is

- in UTF-8 encoding: `%C3%84%C3%96%C3%9C-foobar`
- in ISO-8859-1 encoding: `%C4%D6%DC-foobar`

without `.postDataCharset("ISO-8859-1")`the server received the UTF-8 encoded string:

```
%C3%84%C3%96%C3%9C-foobar
```

with `.postDataCharset("ISO-8859-1")`the server received the ISO-8859-1 encoded string:

```
%C4%D6%DC-foobar
```